# Empty a UIPageViewController (remove ViewControllers inside)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How can I remove all the viewControllers inside a UIPageViewController in Swift?

Those calls:

```
pageViewController.setViewControllers(nil,....)
pageViewController.setViewControllers([UIViewController(),....)
```

both make my app crash with the following message:`The number of view controllers provided (0) doesn't match the number required (1) for the requested transition`

Answer (score 1):

A `UIPageViewController` does not "hold view controllers" in the sense you are thinking of. All it does is display a view controller *returned by its `dataSource`* ... and its `dataSource` is **your** code.

If you simply do this:

```
[pageViewController setViewControllers:@[UIViewController.new] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
```

That *will* replace the current "page" with an empty UIViewController - but it won't do anything else. You'll still be able to scroll, and depending on your next/previous logic, that may result in other errors.

What you'll want to do is "clear" the current page with that line, but then *also* prevent scrolling / swiping. This is often done by setting the `UIPageViewController`'s `dataSource` to nil.

Answer (score 0):

## What Don explained, for 2020:

As @DonMag has explained. Really all you can do is

1. Simply replace the current VC you are seeing, with, a blank one.
2. Set the datasource of the page view controller to null

Important caveats ..

• What does it really mean to have a "blank" VC in your app? It could be, you make as special view controller (which is just "gray clouds" or "an explanation that there is no data" or something) which you use.

• But you can in fact safely just use `UIViewController()` and it will be blank, nothingness.

• With point 2, don't forget to set it back!

## In practice... something like...

```
var vcs: [UIViewController] = []

func reloadPages() {
    print("reload pages in your page view controller")
    let k = yourData.count

    if k == 0 {
        dataSource = nil
        setViewControllers([UIViewController()], direction: .forward, animated: false)
        return
    }
    
    dataSource = self
    
    vcs = []
    for i in 0..<k {
        let vc = _sb("SomePageOfYours") as! SomePageOfYours
        vcs.append(vc)
    }
    
    setViewControllers([vcs[0]], direction: .forward, animated: false)
}
```

In the last line of code, don't forget it's an array of only the first item, not the whole array.

Aside - the call '_sb' is just something that loads your view controller from it's storyboard.  Example,

```
func _sb(_ s: String) -> UIViewController {
    // assume the storyboard id is set as ClassNameID
    return UIStoryboard(name: s, bundle: nil)
       .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: s + "ID")
}
```